# Files on a Windows 2003 share filed server are not releasing locks?

Tags: windows-server-2003, file-sharing, files

What could be causing a windows 2003 file server to no longer release file locks?  The locks are being created and not released by

- Legacy vendor code (C++ I assume)
- Legacy code, VB
- Newer C# code

All with separate logging code (all locks are happening in logs so far).  The problem has been steadily getting worse for the past month, and now is occurring multiple times a day.  The only system wide change we've made recently (patches are staggered across affected and un-affected servers) is a storage change on the file server to [CLARiiON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLARiiON).  What could be causing the locks to not release as they are no longer used?

---

Related: [Windows File Sharing Orphaned File Locks](https://serverfault.com/questions/18742/windows-file-sharing-orphaned-file-locks)

Answer (score 2):

Please us unlocker assistance to check which process is locking the files. You can download it from http://download.cnet.com/Unlocker/3000-2248_4-10493998.html